# The method '+' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: +(123)

Tags: flutter, dart

I get this error and I don't know why. I basically just check the operator and make calculations based on that.

Thank you for your help.

Function:

```
  void calculate() {
    setState(() {
      int num1int = int.tryParse(_num1);
      int num2int = int.tryParse(_num2);
      int result = 0;
      if (_operator == "+") {
        result = num1int + num2int;
      }
      else if (_operator == "-") {
        result = num1int - num2int;
      }
      else if (_operator == "*") {
        result = num1int * num2int;
      }
      else if (_operator == "/") {
        result = num1int ~/ num2int;
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if "int.tryParse" can not convert it into integer, it will be returning "null". So your code does: null + null. You can add a check for num1int and num2int if it is null before calcultion.

Comment: Do you know why he can't ? How can I convert a string into an integer in dart ?

Answer (score 1):

**please change your code to**

```
  if (_operator == "+") {
    result = num1int??0 + num2int??0;
  }
  else if (_operator == "-") {
    result = num1int??0 - num2int??0;
  }
  else if (_operator == "*") {
    result = num1int??1 * num2int??1;
  }
  else if (_operator == "/") {
    result = num1int??1 ~/ num2int??1;
  }
```